# Redshift table creates are not durable/persistent

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

I'm using SqlWorkbenchJ to connect to my Redshift cluster and create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE mydb_dev.Widget (
  fizz BIGINT,
  buzz BIGINT,
  lastRanOn timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT (current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
);  

select * from mydb_dev.Widget;
```

When I run the above SELECT statement, it shows an empty table. So far so good.

**However**, if I disconnect and then reconnect to the cluster, and then run the same exact SELECT again, I get:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
select * from mydb_dev.Widget

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: relation "mydb_dev.Widget" does not exist;
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 0.06s
```

**So it looks like table creates are not durable or persisting the current connection...whats the fix here?!?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Workbench, the default setting for autocommit when creating a new [connection profile](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/profiles.html#profile-autocommit) is "off". So when you create a new connection and don't change anything, autocommit will be disabled and you need to `commit` every transaction.

Alternatively, autocommit can be turned off/on interactively by executing:

```
SET autocommit ON/OFF
```

After creating the table you need to commit it, otherwise, when the current session ends, the created table is removed.

execute `COMMIT` after creating the table.

```
CREATE TABLE mydb_dev.Widget (
  fizz BIGINT,
  buzz BIGINT,
  lastRanOn timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT (current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
);  
COMMIT;
```

Comment: This is quite believable.  But the documentation explicitly says:  "By default, individual Amazon Redshift operations (queries, DDL statements, loads) are automatically committed to the database."  (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_BEGIN.html)  Perhaps the tool is doing this work inside a transaction?

Comment: yes, `sqlworkbenchj` does that and (at least) an earlier version of `postico` did that, i.e. disable auto-commit, i'm sure other clients also do that, and to be fair, it seems like a sensible thing to do @GordonLinoff

Comment: @HaleemurAli . . . You should mention in the answer that sqlworkbenchj turns off auto-commit.  That is really the issue.